# why do javascript functions evaluated onload

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

**Question: Any ideas how to NOT trigger the `confirmOption` function on page load, and *only* trigger it when the button is clicked?**

So in my html body i have:

```
<Body>
<a href="#" id="btn_YES" onclick="<%="send('YES','" + rm.getAction ("YES") + "'); return (false);"%>" class="actionBtn"><span><span>Yes</span></span></a>&#160;
            <a href="#" id="btn_NO" onclick="<%="send('NO','" + rm.getAction ("NO") + "'); return (false);"%>" class="actionBtn"><span><span>No</span></span></a>&#160;
</Body>
```

Javascript functions that have been working fine:

```
function send(button, url) {
    if (opener.document && opener.document.forms[0] && (opener.document.forms[0].elements['sessionToken'] || opener.document.forms[0].elements['screenID']))
         {
                                opener.answer(button, url);
                                window.close();
                            } else { 
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
```

`getAction` and `confirmOption(String option)` are declared in java. If `confirmOption` is evaluated, it will output in the console `YES` or `NO`

```
function setConfirm(userSelection){
        if(userSelection="YES") result = "<%=mb.confirmOption("YES")%>"; 
        if(userSelection="NO") result = "<%=mb.confirmOption("NO")%>";
}
```

When i load the page, why does it print in my console:

```
YES
NO
```

, even before i clicked on the button? My breakpoint on java was triggered, so i can see that the method was being evaluated on page load - when it shouldn't because it should be triggered when the button is clicked.

When i clicked on the button, my breakpoint was NOT triggered and i was sent to the relevant page.

Any ideas how to NOT trigger the `confirmOption` function on page load, and *only* trigger it when the button is clicked?

Comment: Are you saying that the YES and NO is being printed by your Java code on the server. And when you access the JSP page, it prints YES and NO in the console when the page loads? If that is the case then that is expected behaviour. You should figure out why you expect it to be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they wont be evaluated onload. They will get evaluated as soon as browser finds them during loading although you can defer evaluation and in the above can you are actually calling the function remove quotes

Comment: how do i call the function ONLY when the button is clicked?

Comment: It should be like <a href="#" onlick="clickLink">here</a>

Answer (score 0):

the confirmOption function is your server-end function ,which must be executed and turned to be a value before your browser-end code,so,maybe you can use an ajax post to the servlet to trigger it ,instead of using it this way.